# When connecting java to SAP(JCO) through RFC Getting Error

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jco, saprfc

When connecting java to SAP(JCO) through RFC Getting below  Error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/SecretKey
    at com.sap.conn.rfc.engine.GUID$Factory.createGUID(GUID.java:20)
    at com.sap.conn.rfc.driver.RfcTypeDirectCpic.open(RfcTypeDirectCpic.java:79)

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.SecretKey from [Module "com.sap.conn.jco" from local module loader @3aa9e816 (finder: local module finder @17d99`enter code here`928 (roots: /Jboss_EAP7.1/modules,/Jboss_EAP7.1/modules/system/layers/base))]
```

Here i am using java 1.8, linux OS 64bit, Jbose 7.1

I gave JCO properties. but still getting error

Comment: post your JCO connection code here

Comment: I checked it correct only. Do you have references. please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use a Java Runtime Environment with an insufficient Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) for the SAP Java Connector.